# Circle identification and drawing lines through circles in the same vertical line

Tags: python, opencv

I have a simple image with about 15 randomly placed circles. My task is to identify the circles and then draw a straight line through the circles lying on the same vertical line. I am still a beginner in OpenCV.

I initially tried to determine location of the circles and used this code:

```
image = cv2.imread('circle', 0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(image,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 
1,20,param1=40,param2=20,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
   cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2_imshow(cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

This is the output I am getting which does not make any sense to me:

[image]

Kindly help in identifying the circles and drawing a straight line through the circles.

**EDIT:** Input images look like this:

[image: Input]

Comment: I do not think Hough circle will help locate your dots. They are not circular nor large enough. Perhaps using blob detection on a thresholded image may work better to locate the dots.

Comment: can you show your input image?

Comment: I recommend thresholding then contour filtering to isolate your dots. Then depending on the output image, potentially `cv2.HoughLinesP()` to detect the line or perform morphological operations to connect the dots and form a line. Add your original input image so we can test your code :)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/36kGshh This is what the image looks like. They are circular and I need to identify them and draw a straight line through circles lying on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at your input image, I doubt that any of the circles' centers have the same `x` coordinate. That's why, I will set up a tolerance `tol` in my solution, within `x` coordinates are allowed. The final line is then drawn through the mean of these `x` coordinates.

The general approach is as follows:

1. Inverse binary threshold the image, see [`cv2.threshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57) and [`ThresholdTypes`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaa9e58d2860d4afa658ef70a9b1115576), to have white circles on black background, and to get rid of possible JPG artifacts.
2. Find the extreme outer contours , see [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) and [`RetrievalModes`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71).
3. Find the centers and radii of the circles of minimum enclosing area using [`cv2.minEnclosingCircle`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8ce13c24081bbc7151e9326f412190f1).
4. Find the vertical lines by matching `x` coordinates within tolerance as described above.

Here's the code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io              # Only needed for web grabbing images, use cv2.imread for local images

# Read image from web
img = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.imgur.com/VQ5Ri0W.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

# Convert image to grayscale for further processing; inverse binary threshold (also to get rid of JPG artifacts)
_, gray = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Find only external contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
n = len(contours)

# Get center coordinates and radii of all circles (converted to int)
circles = [cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt) for cnt in contours]
centers = np.array([np.int32(np.round(circ[0])) for circ in circles])

# Find vertical lines within tolerance; calculate mean
tol = 10
x_match = np.array([np.abs(centers[:, 0] - cent[0]) < tol for cent in centers])
lines_global = []
for i in np.arange(n):
    lines_local = []
    lines_local.append(i)
    for j in np.arange(i+1, n):
        if (x_match[i, j]):
            lines_local.append(j)
    if (len(lines_local) > 1):
        lines_global.append(np.int32(np.round(np.mean(centers[lines_local, 0]))))
        for j in lines_local:
            for k in lines_local:
                x_match[j, k] = False
                x_match[k, j] = False

# Draw lines
for line in lines_global:
    cv2.line(img, (line, 0), (line, img.shape[0]), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The current output looks like this:

[image: Output]

You can set `tol = 0` to get only exact `x` coordinate matches, but as stated initially, for the given image, you won't find any two circles.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello,Thank you. However, when I try to runit, I am getting an error saying "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" when you convert the image to grayscale.

Comment: @Raju Just to be sure: Did you copy-paste my solution, and run it as is? Can you please provide the whole stack trace? Which OpenCV version do you use? If that line is affected, then the error should arise from the `cv2.threshold` call. I had a look: OpenCV 2.4.x, 3.x, and 4.x all have the same output format, i.e. `retval, dst = cv2.threshold(...)`. Also, it's `dst = cv2.cvtColor(...)` for all mentioned versions. So, I can't figure out any possible version conflicts or similar, so that right now, I can't think of any possible other error.

Comment: findContours can have different number of output for different versions.

Comment: @fmw42 That's why I asked for the whole stack trace. Couldn't imagine, that the error comes from the mentioned line.

Comment: Im sorry for the misinformation. This is the error. It was from the find contours line.    
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-8b0cc3c607bd> in <module>()
      8 
      9 # Find only external contours
---> 10 contours, _ = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
     11 n = len(contours)
     12 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: @Raju Then I guess, you use OpenCV 3.x? As fmw42 already mentioned, the outputs of `cv2.findContours` are different, it's [`image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(...)`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.8/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a). So, change the line in my code to `_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(...)`, and it should work for you, also. Next time, please state the OpenCV version you use, right from the start in your question. That helps to avoid such things. :-)

Comment: I will keep than in mind. Your code works brilliantly for the above image. I tried running it on another image with a similar task: https://imgur.com/a/89avypc but it does not detect any circles.

Comment: @Raju You do understand, that this is a different image modality, and that you have to adapt my solution, especially regarding the pre-processing? Why don't you post your real-life examples in the first place, if they differ that much from what you've provided in your question? Converting to grayscale, and thresholding should work here, too. Only stating "It doesn't work on this or that image" is not helpful at all. I will now stop further supporting here. If you have difficulties, adapting my code, please ask a new question and provide proper information right from the start.